# Save value from a particular tag in a row and add it to another row using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML file:

```
<data>
    <entry>
        <name>Oliver</name>
        <hobby>Reading</hobby>
        <flag>Yes</flag>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Oliver</name>
        <hobby>WindSurfing</hobby>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Bucky</name>
        <hobby>Painting</hobby>
    </entry>
</data>
```

which I'd like to be transformed into:

```
Name   |  Hobby1  |  Hobby2
Oliver | Windsurfing| Reading
Bucky  | Painting |
```

I tried applying for-each and saving the 1st name and hobby value into variables and applying the logic such as:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <text>Name</text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Hobby1</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Hobby2</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="data/entry">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="flag='Yes'">
                    <xsl:variable name="hobby1"><xsl:value-of select="hobby"/></xsl:variable>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="hobby"/>
                    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$hobby1"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is, if the flag value is Yes, and the name is the SAME for the consequent entry, then I'd like to pull the previous hobby value and add it into the next row as shown by the example above. The above logic that I applied, I have defined the variable within the choose expression, so it is out of scope in the next iteration of the for-each loop. I am in a fix. Any help or insight would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: Can you explain the rules to transform that input to that output? What is the meaning of the `flag` element? What decides whether a `hobby` is `hobby1` or `hobby2`? Do you know in advance that each `entry/name` will only be associated with one or two `hobby` elements?

Comment: If we have the `flag` element as yes, then the `hobby` tag within that entry would be shown as `hobby2`  in the output as shown. If there are two `entry` elements with the same name, then one of them **will** have a `flag` element.The `flag` element is there just to determine that the `hobby` tag value within that particular `entry` would be `hobby2`@MartinHonnen

Comment: So the `entry` with `name` "Oliver" has the `hobby` "Reading" and the `flag` as "Yes", yet it shows as "Hobby1" in your output. That doesn't make any sense with the explanation that the `flag`  indicates `hobby2`.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding. "Reading should be under `hobby2`. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It continues to look like a grouping problem to me:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Name', 'Hobby1', 'Hobby2'" separator=" | "/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="data/entry" group-adjacent="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), string(current-group()[not(flag)]/hobby), string(current-group()[flag = 'Yes']/hobby)" separator=" | "/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

The sample and the description, however, don't explain clearly whether you need or want `group-by` or `group-adjacent` or even a more complicated approach (e.g. if there can be more than two adjacent `entry` elements with the same `name` and you would want to create more than one row in that case).